PDF Export with ICC Profile: Ink Coverage Limitation Discrepancy
I aimed to export a PDF with an ICC profile restricting the total ink coverage to 240. However, upon exporting and inspecting the colors, I found that the ink coverage remained at 320, with no alterations.
Indesign, total ink coverage is 320

Export to pdf, set icc profile

check colour, remained at 320, it should reduce below 240.


It seems like you are exporting the PDF with Color Conversion set to Convert to Destination (Preserve Numbers). (I can't read your language, but I notice there's a parenthesis.)
Preserve Numbers means "leave the CMYK values unchanged". Or in other words "only convert RGB and Lab to the chosen CMYK profile".
If you want InDesign to convert from one CMYK profile to another, you have to set Color Conversion to Convert to Destination.
To get the right conversion, you have to make sure that your Document CMYK is set to the profile used in the placed images and graphics. You can change Document CMYK in Edit > Assign Profiles.
The downside of converting like this is that all your CMYK colors will be converted from one profile to another. That means that for example clean 100% black text will change and become a kind of rich black in all four inks. To avoid that you have to convert each object/image manually before exporting.
When previewing and measuring in Acrobat, you have to select the same profile as the one you exported to in InDesign. I notice in your screenshots that the profiles differ.
